# Update specific BQ partition or data range with Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Hello I'm Struggling to find if this is possible to do.
I have a Pipeline that load data from Storage and apply some transformations,
after the transformation is ended I upload that data on BigQuery bu I always need to process the entire
data I have but this process overtime start to be a little bit spicy in terms of GCP billing.

I trying to figuered out some way I can only truncate some partition or delete some range of data to insert a new one.

I created this pseudo code what actually I do.

```
//Create My Pipeline
Pipeline  p  = ....;

//Do some transformations
PCollection<SomeModel> processed_data = p.apply(ParDo....);


//Format the results to Write on BQ
PCollection<TableRow> rows = processed_data.apply("Format to BQ",Map...);

//Save on Bq with partion by Date
rows.apply("Save it",
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tableName).withSchema(TableSchema)
        .withTimePartitioning(new TimePartitioning().setField("date"))
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));

p.run();
```

At end I write to Bigquery using BigQueryIO but I always need to truncate the table

Obs: At least I need to reprocess the last 30 days every day so I can't increment the data daily.

Ob2: I already searched a lot but I can't find a native way to do, I see people recomending to load the data to a table and create a scheduled job to import that to a production table or some sort, or inside  DoFn call the BigQuery API to delete the data before to start your production pipeline.

Comment: so you have a batch pipeline, and you run it - how often? - and when you run it, you want to truncate, and insert all new data - is that correct? - and what's the problem you're hitting as you're building the pipeline?

Comment: hey @Pablo yeah I running a batch pipeline and runs every day, I don't wanna truncate the table every time but I want to  replace only a specific period  example : if my Table has data between jan/20 and nov/20  I just wanna update Nov/20 instead of all data